# SQL Float to VARCHAR using STR

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to convert a float value to a string value with 2 decimal precision using `STR` function. Works well, but i'm getting a wrong number when trying to convert a value of 1.525. I should get 1.53, i get 1.52 instead.

```
Does not work
Select rtrim(ltrim(Str(1.525, 10,2)))       
1.52

Works for these    
Select rtrim(ltrim(Str(1.225, 10,2)))       
1.23

Select rtrim(ltrim(Str(1.325, 10,2)))       
1.33

Select rtrim(ltrim(Str(1.515, 10,2)))       
1.52

Select rtrim(ltrim(Str(1.535, 10,2)))   
1.54
```

UPDATE

I used `FORMAT(floatValue, 'N2')` and it's working properly now. Any comment on using this function, supported on 2012 onward. Also the second argument can be constructed dynamically to support different precision

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  I get different results than those you posted using 2008.

Comment: Why are you using `FLOAT`? `SELECT CONVERT(decimal(12,2), '1.525');`

Comment: FLOAT is not exact -- you can use NUMERIC or DECIMAL types if you want exact

Comment: The conversion doesn't work: SELECT FloatValue,CONVERT(decimal(13,2), FloatValue),CAST(FloatValue AS decimal(10, 2))
FROM dbo.MyTable. Using SQL server 2012

Comment: @ken I still think you'll see way more people using `CAST()` and `CONVERT()` for these use cases. It could be just an opinion thing - working code is more important - but you'll find more examples using those functions than `STR()` and `FORMAT()`. But again, that's totally up to you. Good luck!

Comment: What does "the conversion doesn't work" mean? Also, here is [a pretty strong argument against using `FORMAT()`](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Try `Select rtrim(ltrim(Str(1.525, 10,2)))` to see what i mean. You get 1.52 instead of 1.53

Comment: Thanks, I got that part from your question. I was talking about your comment where you literally said "The conversion doesn't work" and referenced code that doesn't use rtrim, ltrim, or str.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thx for the link. Using Format for now in parts of the system where the number of records is quite small < 1000, in the absence of a better solution, a microseconds performance hit (according to the article) is acceptable for now.

Comment: Exceptions that need excuses are bad ideas, IMHO. I prefer consistency. YMMV.

Comment: @AaronBertrand that's right, What's the alternative though ? I'll be happy to apply it :)

Comment: Well, I would expect `CONVERT()` as I suggested in the article, but you told us "the conversion doesn't work" and I still don't know what that means so I don't know how to tell you to apply it. I would also consider not storing these as floats or strings in the first place. (Also, the `FORMAT()` hit is roughly double in all tests I've done, the measure unit is irrelevant - so choosing something slower for no really good reason other than being slower is acceptable is not a good choice and doesn't scale.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand `Select rtrim(ltrim(Str(1.525, 10,2)))` did you try to run this ? if you get 1.53 with convert or any other way other i'll be very happy to use it. What do you mean not to store as float. What other type do you then instead ?

Comment: Decimal. I don't know why so many people pick float by default, it is useful only in a very narrow set of use cases.

Comment: You still haven't clarified whether the value is stored as a float or a string. If the data type is float, you should either (a) change it, or (b) use two converts to prevent direct conversion to decimal from losing the proper rounding. `DECLARE @f float = 1.525; SELECT @f, CONVERT(decimal(10,2),CONVERT(decimal(10,3),@f));`  Really, (a) is the better way, IMHO, because: `DECLARE @d decimal(10,3) = 1.525; SELECT ROUND(@d,2);`

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to convert the string to a numeric type (rounded to two decimals) and then do something else with it, I would use `CAST()` (or `CONVERT()`) 100% of the time, possibly with `ROUND()` and other functions, but in your case the precision used with `CAST()` does our rounding for us.

Here is an alternate form of your problem query:

```
Select cast(cast('1.525' as numeric(10, 2)) as varchar(11));
-- returns '1.53'
-- note that I don't really have to recast it as a varchar, 
--     but that's what type your example query would return,
--     so I tried to match that
```

Why exactly are you insisting on using `STR()` for this?

Comment: i use STR because the precision is dynamic, RTRIM(LTRIM(STR(@value, 102, ISNULL(@precision, 2)))). Anyways, your solution still give the wrong answer 1.52 as the value is a float type originally. I tried rounding and it's not accurate. Between, i'm suing SQL Server 2012

Comment: Something to be aware of https://siderite.blogspot.com/2014/04/converting-float-values-to-string-in-t.html#at3243721726

Comment: @ken in your example you did not use a float, you used a string.  I see in your question where you say it is a float.  Why don't you change your example queries to show float values being used instead of strings?  Even `cast('1.525' as float)` would be more representative than just `'1.525'`.